# Google Sheets Error - Resource at URL not found

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

When i try to get Yahoo Finance stock price importxml return error. Anyone know solve for this problem?

```
B2 = ASTOR.IS

P2 = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&B2&"/key-statistics?p="&B2

AM2 = /html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/fin-streamer[1]

=IMPORTXML(P2, AM2)
```

Comment: Please, add the description of the error you get

Comment: formula return;Error
Resource at URL not found.